# Using python to send a single int over ethernet

Tags: python, ethernet, socketserver

I need to make a server that recieves and sends single integers using tcp. Socketserver gives me a TypeError if i try to do this. Is there an alternative or do i need to write a server from scratch?

Comment: why don't you show us some relevant code? socketserver probably wants you to input a string or byte array... so you'll just have to serialize your integer to a byte array!

Comment: you need to serialize your `int` e.g., using `cPickle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html)